# my site (ASP.NET webForm ) log out with out user request

Tags: asp.net

my site (ASP.NET webForm ) log out with out user request , user forced to login page and interrupt his work ? please advice ...
this line from my web.config

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/XXXXXXX.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the Session timeout value, by default this is 30 minutes.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Account/XXXXXXX.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>

    <sessionState timeout="3000"  />
</system.web>
```